# Symfony2 App with RESTful authentication, using FOSRestBundle and FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, restful-authentication, fosrestbundle

I'm making REST API for my JS driven app.

During login, the login form is submitted via AJAX to url `/rest/login` of my API.

- If the login is succesful, it returns 204
- If it fails, it returns 401

While I have separated firewalls for the API and the app itself, they share the same context which should mean, that when user authenticates against the API, he's authenticated against the app too. So, when the server returns 204, page will reload and it should redirect user to the app, because he's now logged in.

I tried to use pre-made `check_login` page of the FOSUserBundle and pointed `/rest/login` there.

```
login:
    path: /rest/login
    defaults:
        _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check
    methods: [ POST ]
```

That doesn't work, because it always returns redirect, no matter what. I read documentation for symfony and couldn't find, how to make a custom `check_login` page. What I need is something like this

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;    

class SecurityController {

    /**
     * @View(statusCode=204)
     */
    public function loginAction($username, $password) {

        /* first I need to somehow authenticate user 
           using normal authentication, that I've set up */
        ...

        /* Then I need to return 204 or throw exception,
           based on result.
           This is done using FOSRestBundle and it's
           listeners. */

        if(!$succesful) {
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have a clue how to do that. Nothing I found in any documentation helped me a bit. I will be thankful for any suggestion that would point me in right direction.

---

EDIT: To further simplify, what I'm aiming for. I want my login to function exactly the same as normal *form_login*. I only want to change the response, that it sends back - instead of redirect I want 204 on success and 401 on failure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to find a simple solution. I only needed to write a class, that implements `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` and `AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface`.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;

class AuthenticationRestHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface {

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        return new Response('', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
        return new Response('', Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

Then I registered it as a service and configured as handlers for the firewall.

```
services:
  security.authentication_rest_handler:
    class: AuthenticationRestHandler

security:
  firewalls:
    rest:
      pattern: ^rest
      context: app
      form_login:
        check_path: /rest/login
        provider: fos_userbundle
        failure_handler: inspireon.security.authentication_rest_handler
        success_handler: inspireon.security.authentication_rest_handler
        username_parameter: login
        password_parameter: password
```

Problem solved and no complicated authentication provider needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I understood your problem because I passed by a similar situation but with SOAP services. In the middle I could re-search the security wsse and Symfony2 has already provides a solution

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

It works with a real token and you can match with an user in FOSUserBundle. The only think that I see is the field "password" that you want to compare is the same that in the database (with encryption) then I decided to create a extra field only for this use.

I hope that it help you.

Greetings

Comment: So, do I need to implement whole new custom authentication provider? Imo it's a bit overkill, because all I need to change is the behaviour of the listener to send 204/401 instead of redirect, not the whole process.