# FOS UserBundle Login from external Site (use as API in Cordova)

Tags: jquery, cordova, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a project that utilizes the FOS UserBundle for my Login.
I now want to write a Cordova App that logs in this project and gets data I provide via JSON.

I have this, which works on local:

```
$.get('http://192.168.10.30/app_dev.php/login', function (data) {
    */ Get Token */
    var $result = $(data).find('input:hidden[name="_csrf_token"]');
    $.post('http://192.168.10.30/app_dev.php/login_check', {
        _csrf_token: $result.val(),
        target_path: 'mainPage',
        _username: 'USERNAME',
        _password: 'PASSWORD'
    }).done(function (postData) {
        console.log(postData);
    });
});
```

`postData` shows everything I need. But this only works on the dev server, as it is the same origin.

Moving it to an app would cause it to give me a Cross Origin Alert, I know that. The question is, is this even the right way to approach such a thing?

How else can I get "behind" the login of my Project from the outside?

Comment: check this bundle, we managed to accept REST logins with it: https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

Comment: This is awesome! Any hint to perform a FOSUserBundle Login?

Comment: for a very easy solution check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075078/symfony2-app-with-restful-authentication-using-fosrestbundle-and-fosuserbundle, for a bit more complex e.g.: https://gist.github.com/tjamps/11d617a4b318d65ca583